# Como saber a rota atual no Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-rotas

No Laravel 5, podemos pegar a rota atual (digo a instância da classe) utilizando a classe `Illuminate\Http\Request`, através do método `route`.

Assim:

```
 public function handle(Request $request)
 {
       $rota = $request->route();
 }
```

E no Laravel 4? Como posso fazer isso?

Preciso saber, em determinado momento, qual é a rota atual que está sendo requisitada.

Por exemplo:

```
  App::before(function ($request)
  {
      $rota = /** Quero descobrir como pegar a rota atual aqui **/
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muito bem, Senhor @WallaceMaxters! Isso é muito simples.

Basta você utilizar o método `Route::getCurrentRoute()`.

É primeiramente importante lembrar que isso só vai funcionar em `filters` e no `App::after`. No `App::before` não vai funcionar, pois pela lógica, a rota ainda não foi processada, para que a instância seja retornada pelo `Laravel`.

Aí vai um exemplo:

```
 Route::filter('auth', function ()
 {
       dd(Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName());
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName()
```

O legal é que também funciona nas outras versões (as maiores que o **4**) do *Laravel*

Comment: Mas isso já estava respondido, não?